# Why my menu hover effect disappear on hovering second step menu?

Tags: html, css

So I don't even now how simply explain my problem. I have simple two step menu. When you hover on first step of menu hovered element change color and second step of menu appear. And there is my problem: 
When I hover on second step of menu element of first step (this one which you hover to show second step) change color to default, like hovering on this first step never happend.
For example: one element of first step is called ipsum. When I hover over "ipsum" second step menu appear and "ipsum" change its color. When I hover over second step menu, which just showed up, "ipsum" change color to default color of menu.
I tried to discover why it happens but I have no idea.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/*main menu*/
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
/*all links in menu*/
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404040;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background-color 0.8s;
}
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
.menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #ababab;
}


/*second step menus*/
.sStep {
  position: absolute;

  /*to nice 'fade in'*/
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;

  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ababab;
}
.sStep > li {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
.sStep > li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
.sStep > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.sStep > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #909090;
}

/*'fade in hover' */
.menu > li:hover > .sStep {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>menu2</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ipsum</a>
          <ul class="sStep">
              <li><a href="#">Suspendisse</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Donec commodo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">sodales consectetur</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Maecenas sit amet</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mauris tempor vitae sem</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Curabitur</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">amet</a>
          <ul class="sStep">
            <li><a href="#">ullamcorper cursus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cras blandit nunc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">fermentum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Neque porro quisquam</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this bit:

```
.menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #ababab;
}
```

To this:

```
.menu > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #ababab;
}
```

They key is you want the `hover` state to be affected when hovering anywhere on the `<li>` including the submenu.

Demo below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*main menu*/

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 0; /* remove gaps between inline-blocks */
}


/*all links in menu*/

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #404040;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background-color 0.8s;
}

.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem; /* change from em to rem */ 
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #ababab;
}


/*second step menus*/

.sStep {
  position: absolute;
  /*to nice 'fade in'*/
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ababab;
}

.sStep>li {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

.sStep>li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.sStep>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sStep>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #909090;
}


/*'fade in hover' */

.menu>li:hover>.sStep {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ipsum</a>
      <ul class="sStep">
        <li><a href="#">Suspendisse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donec commodo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sodales consectetur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Maecenas sit amet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mauris tempor vitae sem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Curabitur</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">amet</a>
      <ul class="sStep">
        <li><a href="#">ullamcorper cursus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cras blandit nunc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">fermentum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Neque porro quisquam</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have an another question:
When I run snippet noticed little gap between each of menu elements. Can you explain me that? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: @Daniel1490 I've edited two lines to the demo to show how to remove gaps between your inline-block elements. I added `font-size: 0` to `.menu` (so the spaces between elements occupy no space) and then changed `font-size: 1.5em` to `1.5rem` on `.menu > li`.